# How to play media file in embedded Linux with ffplay?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, multimedia

I am currently working on an embedded Linux system (kernel-5.10.24) that includes an LCD and a speaker.

At the moment, I am testing the playback of media files using ffmpeg and ffplay, without utilizing SDL. Initially, I attempted the following approach and encountered an error.

```
# ffplay /test.mp4
ffplay version 4.2.2 Copyright (c) 2003-2019 the FFmpeg testers
  built with gcc 7.2.0 (GNU Linux-Release5.0.0.0-Default(ARMv5))
  configuration: --enable-cross-compile --cross-prefix=/test/armv5/gitdir/linux_gnu_armv5/out/product/fooarmv5.tea5.10-eng/obj/bin/arm-linux-gnu- --sysroot=/test/armv5/gitdir/linux_gnu_armv5/out/product/fooarmv5.tea5.10-eng/obj/host/arm-linux-gnu/sysroot --host-cc=/usr/bin/gcc --arch=arm --target-os=linux --disable-stripping --pkg-config=/test/armv5/gitdir/linux_gnu_armv5/out/product/fooarmv5.tea5.10-eng/obj/host/bin/pkg-config --disable-static --enable-shared --prefix=/usr --enable-avfilter --disable-version3 --enable-logging --enable-optimizations --disable-extra-warnings --enable-avdevice --enable-avcodec --enable-avformat --enable-network --disable-gray --enable-swscale-alpha --disable-small --enable-dct --enable-fft --enable-mdct --enable-rdft --disable-crystalhd --disable-dxva2 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --disable-hardcoded-tables --disable-msa --enable-hwaccels --disable-cuda --disable-cuvid --disable-nvenc --disable-avisynth --disable-frei0r --disable-libopencore-amrnb --disable-libopencore-amrwb --disable-libdc1394 --disable-libgsm --disable-libilbc --disable-libvo-amrwbenc --disable-symver --disable-doc --disable-gpl --disable-nonfree --enable-ffmpeg --enable-ffplay --enable-avresample --disable-ffprobe --disable-libxcb --disable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-indevs --enable-alsa --enable-outdevs --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --enable-lzo --disable-bzlib --disable-libfdk-aac --disable-libcdio --disable-gnutls --enable-openssl --enable-libdrm --disable-libopenh264 --disable-vaapi --disable-vdpau --disable-mmal --disable-omx --disable-omx-rpi --disable-libopencv --disable-libopus --disable-libvpx --disable-libass --disable-libbluray --disable-libmfx --disable-librtmp --disable-libmp3lame --disable-libmodplug --disable-libspeex --disable-libtheora --disable-libwavpack --disable-iconv --enable-libfreetype --disable-fontconfig --disable-libopenjpeg --disable-libx264 --disable-libx265 --disable-libdav1d --disable-libvo_amrwbenc --disable-libopencore-amrwb --disable-x86asm --disable-mmx --disable-sse --disable-sse2 --disable-sse3 --disable-ssse3 --disable-sse4 --disable-sse42 --disable-avx --disable-avx2 --disable-armv6 --disable-armv6t2 --disable-vfp --disable-neon --disable-altivec --extra-libs=-latomic --enable-pic --cpu=armv5
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
Could not initialize SDL - No available video device
(Did you set the DISPLAY variable?)
```

And I got the same error when run `ffplay /test.mp4`.
But I can play the video with `ffmpeg -re -i /test.mp4  -c:v rawvideo -pix_fmt bgra -f fbdev /dev/fb0`.

There is NO libSDL or X in this embedded system.

So how can I play the MP4 with `ffplay` ?
Even more, how to play the MP3 file with `ffplay` in the system ?

##### Tried with mpv.

```
# mpv -vo help
Available video outputs:
  libmpv           render API for libmpv
  gpu              Shader-based GPU Renderer
  null             Null video output
  image            Write video frames to image files
  tct              true-color terminals
  drm              Direct Rendering Manager

Segmentation fault
```

Then tried to play mp4.

```
# mpv ./Quad_split.mp4
Compiled without libass.
There will be no OSD and no text subtitles.
Playing: ./test.mp4
 (+) Video --vid=1 (*) (h264 852x480 29.895fps)
Error opening/initializing the selected video_out (--vo) device.
Video: no video
No video or audio streams selected.


Exiting... (Errors when loading file)
Segmentation fault
```

I did NOT find /dev/fb, so I tried followings,

```
# mpv --vo image /root/test.mp4
Compiled without libass.
There will be no OSD and no text subtitles.
Playing: /root/test.mp4
 (+) Video --vid=1 (*) (h264 852x480 29.895fps)
VO: [image] 852x480 yuv420p
[vo/image] Saving 00000001.jpg
V: 00:00:00 / 00:00:09 (0%)
[vo/image] Saving 00000002.jpg
V: 00:00:00 / 00:00:09 (1%)
[vo/image] Saving 00000003.jpg
V: 00:00:00 / 00:00:09 (1%)
[vo/image] Saving 00000004.jpg
V: 00:00:00 / 00:00:09 (1%)
[vo/image] Saving 00000005.jpg
V: 00:00:00 / 00:00:09 (2%)
[vo/image] Saving 00000006.jpg
V: 00:00:00 / 00:00:09 (2%)
[vo/image] Saving 00000007.jpg
V: 00:00:00 / 00:00:09 (2%)
[vo/image] Saving 00000008.jpg
```

There are lots of JPG files generated in the current directory, which showed the `mpv` can work to some extent.

So how to make `mpv` to work in this embedded system (without X and VT)? Does it need to do some coding with libmpv to play the video on `/dev/fb`?

Comment: Maybe you could use `mpv` instead.

Comment: I tried mpv, but I got `segfault` with`mpv /test.mp4`.  Either will be OK for me, but current neither is working.

Comment: I doubt `mpv` will work, if `ffplay` doesn't. Did you try to run the command with the `-nodisp` option?

Comment: Run `mpv -vo help`, try to find a video output driver which works. Makes sense to try a GIT version. Makes even more sense to file a bug report.

Comment: I tried `mpv` and updated the question with my testing results. I still cannot play MP4 with directly running `mpv`.